# Find the indices of rows in one data frame that exist in another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.

df1:

|  | Name | Place | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | NY | 0 |
| 1 | Alex | London | 10 |
| 2 | Bob | Sydney | 20 |
| 3 | Will | Munich | 15 |
| 4 | Alex | London | 10 |

df2:

|  | Name | Place | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | NY | 0 |
| 1 | Alex | London | 10 |
| 2 | Tim | HK | 6 |

I want an output as follows:
df2:

|  | Name | Place | Price | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | NY | 0 | [0] |
| 1 | Alex | London | 10 | [1,4] |
| 2 | Tim | HK | 6 | Empty list |

I tried:

```
index_list = []
for row in df2.rows: 
  i = df1[(df1['Name'] == row['Name']) & (df1['Place'] == row['Place']) & (df1['Price'] == row['Price']].index
  index_list.append(i.to_list()) 
df2['Index'] = index_list
```

Is there an efficient (and elegant) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you have in mind; a merge, coupled with a groupby works:

```
grouper = [*df_2.columns]
(df_1.reset_index()
     .merge(df_2, on = grouper)
     .groupby(grouper, sort = False, as_index = False)
     .index
     .agg(list)
  )

   Name   Place  Price   index
0  John      NY      0     [0]
1  Alex  London     10  [1, 4]
```

Comment: Hey! This almost solves it but messes up the ordering. Any way to retain the order?

Comment: Add sort = False?